# haproxy with SSL in front of apache for local development

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy, localhost

I work on a web app that regularly makes AJAX calls to a REST server that (in production) is accessed via the same domain. While developing locally, I have been redirecting REST calls to a dev server using haproxy to get around browser cross origin request restrictions.

haproxy.cfg

```
global
 maxconn 4096
 pidfile ~/tmp/haproxy.pid

defaults
 log global
 log 127.0.0.1 local0
 log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice  
 mode http
 timeout connect 300000
 timeout client 300000
 timeout server 300000
 maxconn 2000
 option redispatch
 retries 3
 option httpclose
 option httplog
 option forwardfor
 option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.0


frontend dev
   bind *:8080 ssl crt /path/to/proxy.pem

    acl                             allow_php               path_beg /app/
    acl                             allow_rest              path_beg /rest/

    use_backend                     be_php                  if allow_php
    use_backend                     be_rest                 if allow_rest

backend be_php
 balance roundrobin
 server localhost_80 localhost:80

backend be_rest
 balance roundrobin
 server dev_80 dev.example.com:80
```

This works as expected:

- `https://localhost:8080/app/login` displays the same as `http://localhost/app/login`
- `https://localhost:8080/rest/test` response is the same as `http://dev.example.com/rest/test`

The problem arises when I attempt to configure haproxy for SSL between HAproxy and the backends (which expect SSL).

According to all the documentation I have read, the following changes should have me all set:

```
backend be_php
    balance roundrobin
    server localhost_443 localhost:443 ssl verify none

backend be_rest
    balance roundrobin
    server dev_443 dev.example.com:443 ssl verify none
```

But after making these changes, `https://localhost:8080` requests time out. Both the php backend and REST backend can be accessed directly via `https://localhost/app/...` and `https://dev.example.com/rest/...`

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: Updated to reflect @Michael-sqlbot's comment

Comment: Pass-through means pass-through. For the most part, it's opaque.  You can't use layer 7 fetches like `path_beg` when you're trying to do pass-through.  Far simpler would be to put an self-signed or free (Lets Encrypt, StartSSL) cert on the proxy and let it make an SSL connection to the back-ends so you can continue to operate in HTTP mode.

Comment: ah got it. I was able to get it working with a self-signed cert and operate in http mode, but I am unable to re-encrypt before sending to the backends. adding `ssl verify none` to the `server` lines in the backends causes requests to timeout

Comment: I updated my question to reflect your comment

Comment: Check the logs.  There is a 4-character code for [session state at disconnect](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.6.html#8.5), which is `----` for a normal connection where everything worked as expected.   Usually, the first two characters will give you a good idea what went wrong, otherwise.  Note that they are case sensitive, so the first position might have e.g. `S` or `s`, which means two different things.